# get a string before the first "." with php

Tags: php

"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."

from

"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

how can we do that ? is there a good function in php for doing things like this ?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: we are at really basic here xD

Comment: sory, but i need to know what people say about this :), see explode and strpos this is why i love stackoverflow.

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/string ? People wont't say anything you can't find in the manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// fastest way
echo substr($text, 0, strpos('.', $text));
```

Answer (score 5):

For PHP 5.3 and later you could use the before_needle argument with strstr:

```
strstr( $youstringhere, ".", true );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split it using the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$sentences = explode (".", $text);
// first sentence is in $sentences[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this *(others have suggested using `explode` -- so I'm suggesting another solution)* :

```
$str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

if (preg_match('/^([^\.]*)/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1] . '.';
}
```

The regex will :

- Start at beginning of string : `^`
- Match anything that's not a . : `[^\.]`
- Any number of times : `[^\.]*`

And, as you wanted a `.` at the end of the output and that `.` is not matched by the regex, you'll have to add it back when using what's been found by the regex.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $matches[0]?

Comment: @Canuteson the first captured *(between parethesis in the pattern)* segment is in `$matches[1]` -- here, as the parenthesis are arround the whole pattern, though, `$matches[0]` and `$matches[1]` will contain the same thing

Comment: regex, like a chainsaw, can be very useful in certain situations. For as simple a process as this, it is a bit overkill.

Comment: One have to learn basic strings to solve such questions himself. Regexps will do no good for him.

Comment: True, regex is overkill here. But I think it is a good answer to broaden the range of answers. All others (`substr()`, `strstr()`, `explode()` etc.) have already been mentioned (some even multiple times).

Answer (score 3):

You could use explode() to get the first sentence. 
http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php