# get olny textnumeric, alt, src and ? from the first 100 letters. useing php

Tags: php

example i have a $text

```
<p>this is a link <a href="/link" class="u">a link</a> hello this is a text then a <img src="www.link.com/image.png">. then i have something like %,$,<?php etc ?> but i dont wanna lose my numbers and ? sign how can we do that?</p>;
```

and somehow

i need it just like

> this is a link a link hello this is a www.link.com/image.png.
>   text then a. then i have something
>   like etc but i dont wanna lose my
>   numbers and ? sign how can we do that?
>   ( first 100 words )

summery

- somehow delete the tags, image ( somehow change it with the src or alt instead )
- delete $, # etc, except the '?' sign
- get the first 100 words
- get the numbers too

for the 100 words i think [get a string before the first "." with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585947/get-a-string-before-the-first-with-php) have a great answer to it. im not quite sure useing regex or ? for this one.

Thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$text = '<p>this is a link <a href="/link" class="u">a link</a> hello this is a text then a <img src="www.link.com/image.png">. then i have something like %,$,etc but i dont wanna lose my numbers and ? sign how can we do that?</p>';
$text = preg_replace('/<a.*? href="(.*?)".*?>.*?<\/a>/i', 'http://link.com$1.', $text);
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = str_replace(array('$,','#,', '%,'), array('', ''), $text);
preg_match('/^((?:\w*?\W){0,100})/', $text, $m);
$text = $m[1];
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
this is a link http://link.com/link. hello this is a text then a . then i have something like etc but i dont wanna lose my numbers and ? sign how can we do that?
```

Comment: what does $text = preg_replace('/ <(\w*?).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/', ' $1', $text); mean ? and why use ob start?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove some test code. I edited my answer, now it's ok